# How can I solve "Runtime Error" on OJ

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to solve the classic TOP K problem on OJ:Given an array,count the largest K number and output them in an ascending order.
My solution is to construct a MAX ROOT HEAP,and delete K times.When I put them on OJ,it told me "Runtime Error" and gave me the correct input and output.But I download the input file and test on my own PC,it's correct. So what's the problem with my code?Is there any illegal operation cause the "Runtime Error"?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long long N,K;
long long * maxHeap;
long long size = 0;

void insertItem(long long * maxHeap)
{
    long long item;
    cin >> item;
    long long pos = ++size;
    for  ( pos; maxHeap[pos / 2] <= item; pos /= 2 )    maxHeap[pos] = maxHeap[pos / 2];
    maxHeap[pos] = item;
}

long long deleteItem(long long * maxHeap)
{
    long long max_item = maxHeap[1];
    long long item = maxHeap[size--];
    long long parent = 1;
    long long child;
    for ( parent; parent * 2 <= size; parent = child ) {
        child = parent * 2;
        if ( child < size && maxHeap[child] < maxHeap[child + 1] )  child++;
        if ( item > maxHeap[child] )    break;
        else    maxHeap[parent] = maxHeap[child];
    }
    maxHeap[parent] = item; 
    return max_item;
}

int main()
{
//  freopen("F://input.txt","r",stdin);
    cin >> N;
    maxHeap = new long long[N];
    maxHeap[0] = 1000000000;
    for ( long long i = 0; i < N; i++ ) insertItem(maxHeap);
    cin >> K;
    for ( long long i = 0; i < K; i++ ) cout << deleteItem(maxHeap) << endl;
    delete[] maxHeap;
    return 0;
}
```

The input sample download from OJ:
19
11  2132  45 445 654 34 44 5645 68 455 32 56 51 63 47 453 554 655 761
10

Output:
5645
2132
761
655
654
554
455
453
445
68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong. Ignoring the ambiguous call to `size` (call it something else, e.g. mysize), it seems like you are going out of bounds somewhere in your code.

In your example, `N` is equal to 19, thus your `maxHeap` array should be indexed from 0 to 19-1=18.

However, here, for instance, you access it to 19:

```
for  ( pos; maxHeap[pos / 2] <= item; pos /= 2 )
    maxHeap[pos] = maxHeap[pos / 2];
```

Add a print statement of `pos` in the body of the loop if you do not believe me.

Comment: Ahhhhh...Got It.

Comment: How careless am I!And I edit the call in main function `maxHeap = new long long[N + 1];`